# Configure PIC port for input and output

Tags: io, port, pic18

I'm trying to use two pins of Port A on my PIC18F4620, with one as an output and the other as an input. I've written a simple program that should do this. However, when I debug the program on my board, the output doesn't change according to the input.

I understand why it would be necessary to change the pin configuration every time if I was only using one pin, but the fact that I'm using two different pins (A0 and A1) has me confused. Also, the output does change when I use two different ports (ex. A0 and D1).

Am I missing something, or is this a limitation I have to work around in my design?

Here is the code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"

void main(void){
    TRISAbits.RA0 = 1;
    TRISAbits.RA1 = 0;

    while(1){
        if(PORTAbits.RA0 == 1){
            LATAbits.LA1 = 0;
        }
        else{
            LATAbits.LA1 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Port A on the PIC18F4620 is multiplexed with the analog/digital converter, so you have to configure some settings before being able to use Port A as digital I/O. Take a look at page 91 of the datasheet:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39626e.pdf

And change your code to the following:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"

void main(void){

    ADCON1 = 0x0F;  // Configure A/D for digital input/output on all pins
    CMCON = 0x07;   // Configure comparator for digital input/output

    TRISAbits.RA0 = 1;
    TRISAbits.RA1 = 0;

    while(1){
        if(PORTAbits.RA0 == 1){
            LATAbits.LA1 = 0;
        }
        else{
            LATAbits.LA1 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```